# Language Attribute for C++/CLI assembly

Tags: visual-c++, resources, c++-cli, embedded-resource

My C++/CLI assembly shows Langauge as English (United States) 
(right click assembly > chose properties > Details tab)

I tried, changing following, but it is not changing at all. I am not sure where this value is being populated from.

AssemblyInfo.cpp

```
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute("en-US")];
```

app.rc

```
  BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
  BEGIN
     BLOCK "040904B0"
```

Changing the 0409 to something else does not change the Language value in the details tab.

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be talking about the Details tab in the shell properties window.  It can only display unmanaged properties, they are not relevant in managed code.  The Language property is set by this section in the VERSIONINFO resource:

```
BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
BEGIN
    VALUE "Translation", 0x409, 1200
END
```

Altering in the 0x409 value to the LCID of another language also changes the displayed Language in the shell property sheet.

Comment: Yep, I found this answer somewhere. 
Thanks.